# Android devices with pressure sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors, pressure

Are there any Android devices out there that have a barometric pressure sensor?

I know that the android.hardware.Sensor class has a [`TYPE_PRESSURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_PRESSURE) constant and the `getAltitude` method in `SensorManager` almost mentions [atmospheric pressure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getAltitude%28float,%20float%29).

So, are there any Android phones out there that have a barometer on them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sony Ericsson Xperia Active seems like will have too a barometer, but will be without the gyro sensor.

Answer (score 7):

Yandex.Market lists most of [Android phones with barometer](https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--mobilnye-telefony/54726/list?hid=91491&glfilter=4925670%3A12105164&glfilter=8547228%3A1&onstock=0&deliveryincluded=0&local-offers-first=0) ever available. The site primarily serves Russian audience (and is in Russian language), but most phones are available internationally.

Comment: I wonder if Samsung Gear has a barometric sensor?

Comment: @Toucouleur Just updated the link.

Answer (score 3):

The [Motorola Xoom](http://www.motorola.com/staticfiles/Consumers/xoom-android-tablet/us-en/techspecs.html) has a barometer. I don't know of any phones, though.

Probably as high-end Honeycomb phones start showing up it will be more common.

Comment: Thanks! just saw that. Any other devices?

Comment: As I said in the (updated) answer, it will be probably more common in some time. I guess it's the first of a trend.

Comment: Thanks for answering, marking the other one as the answer because I was looking for a phone. +1

Answer (score 2):

samsung galaxy nexus has

+gyro + gps

Answer (score 2):

The big new one here is the Galaxy S3.  Phone list has at least these.

Xperia Active.
Xperia Go.
Galaxy S3.
Galaxy Nexus.
Galaxy Note.
Galaxy Note2

I am logging the presence of the pressure sensor in the analitics I gather for my biking app IpBike.  I have seen plenty of Actives ANT support and being waterproof makes it ideal for a bike computer.  I have also seen it for a Galaxy Nexus and some Galaxy Notes and S3.  Not seen a Go yet but I expect I will soon.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody has yet mentioned the Nexus 4. It's pretty good, too; I've developed an altimeter app aimed at pilots using it.

The Nexus 10 also has a pressure sensor, but that's not a phone; it's a tablet.

Comment: Nexus 5 also has an altimeter